# Checking what scanf returns and clearing for new input

Tags: c, scanf

I am brand new to coding and am in an intro class. I need to be able to check what scanf returns and clear it if a float is not entered. When characters are entered into this piece of code, an infinite loop ensues. Any help on how I could implement something into my code to clear scanf and allow characters to be entered without a loop starting? Thanks.

```
do // while loop to gather Resistor B value

{

printf("Enter a value for Resistor Rb (kOhms):  "); // Second Resistor Value
scanf("%f", &rb);

    if(rb < 1 || rb > 100) // Will print Invalid selection if not in range
    
        printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
        
    else
    {
    
        checkstd_rb (rb); // runs function to check if standard value for rb
        
    }
        
}while (rb < 1 || rb > 100); // do while loop ends if a valid input is read
```

Comment: If you want to check what scanf returns, you should inspect its return value.

Comment: since you're reading `rb` as a float, you might also want to compare with against `1.0f` and `100.0f` as well.

Comment: Always, without fail, you *must* check the return value of scanf.  The simplest solution is to emit an error message and abort if scanf does not match any conversion specifiers.  (eg, you have "%f" but the user entered "b").  It is not clear what you mean by "clear it".  Probably you mean that you want to discard input that is invalid.  Since you are beginning, I highly recommend you do not do that, but simply abort and print an error message when you encounter invalid input.

Comment: The `scanf` family of function actually [return a value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) for you to check. But if you want better error handling I suggest you read a whole line (for example with [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)) and then either use `sscanf` or [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) to convert the input to a `float`.